# Scala: list content of all the variables of an object whithout knowing the defintion of the object

Tags: scala

I would like to be able to extract the content of all the val declared in an object, but I don't find a way to do this. So, is it even possible?

example:
I have an object like this:

```
object obj {
  val firstField = "I am the first field"
  val secondField = "I am the second field"
  val thirdField = "I am the third field"
}
```

I want to end up with an sequence like this:

```
Seq("I am the first field", "I am the second field", "I am the third field")
```

Here is what I tried:

```
obj.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(field ⇒ field.get())
```

but it return an error which tells me the method get() does not have the right to access the private final val and I don't find way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fields" in scala are modeled as methods, roughly speaking.

You can do `obj.getClass.getMethods.map(_.invoke(obj))` to do what you want in this case (obviously, you'd have to think of something more elaborate in cases where your object has "real" methods in addition to the ones that were synthesized to model fields).

Also, I have to say, the reason you are getting a rather cold reception for your question is that it is kinda weird. I can't think of a good reason doing something like this would be useful (especially, at the level where a person does not know how to do it), and my guess is that people downvoting your question cannot either.

More likely than not, the solution you have in mind is a wrong one for the problem you are trying to solve. You may be better off telling us what it is you *really* want to do to being with.

Comment: Thanks, I am mostly experimenting with the language but I do have a use case for this.

In my team, we define constant values in a separated object dedicated to it. In my use case, the object contain the path to value stored in a conf. Now, when the program start, I need to check if the path described in my object exist in the conf file. And I am too lazy to rewrite a Seq(path1, path2) each time I modify the conf so I want it to be handle automatically. And since the program is a service, It is not very important if it takes more time because this part will be executed only once.

Comment: It works but I have to use 'obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.map(_.invoke(obj))' 
Otherwise, I have the basic methods inherited from object.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "if path exists in config"? If you are talking about checking whether config file exists at the given path, you should check that when loading config. If you mean checking whether the referenced property exists in config (or a file referenced by the property in config exists), you should check that when the value is initialized. Either way I don't see any need to traverse fields of the object like that.

Comment: Well, that is not the standard where I am currently working but I will think about your point of view.
We check if the conf namespace exist and if it does not, throw a custom error so that we know there is an issue with the configuration.

Comment: It would be checked anyway, when the value is loaded.

Comment: I know, but not signal the same way

Comment: It can signal in whatever way you tell it.